# Get env property by dynamic key in Jenkins scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a problem with getting `env` properties dynamically in Jenkins Scripted Pipeline. I have a String key in the pipeline. Let's call it `key`.
The `key` is obtained by concatenating two strings:

```
def key = env.BRANCH_NAME + ".HOST";
```

And then I wanna get another `env` property by that key:

```
def remoteHost = env[key];
```

But it doesn't work for me.

**Original problem.**

I have three branches in my repository: `dev`, `testing` and `staging`. Also I have three global properties: `dev.HOST`, `testing.HOST`, `staging.HOST`. I want to write something like this:

```
timestamps {
    node() {
        String remoteHost;
        stage('Defining a remote host') {
            def key = env.BRANCH_NAME + ".HOST";
            remoteHost = env[key];
            echo "remote host:" + remoteHost;
    }
}
```

But as I said env[key] not working there. And I get the next stack trace:

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods getAt java.lang.Object java.lang.String
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectStaticMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:279)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetArray(SandboxInterceptor.java:475)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$11.call(Checker.java:484)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetArray(Checker.java:489)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getArray(SandboxInvoker.java:45)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ArrayAccessBlock.rawGet(ArrayAccessBlock.java:21)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:36)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor131.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock$LocalVariable.get(LocalVariableBlock.java:39)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.LocalVariableBlock.evalLValue(LocalVariableBlock.java:28)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$BlockImpl.eval(LValueBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock.eval(LValueBlock.java:16)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:136)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

How could I get property right? Or how could I solve this problem?
Jenkins version: `2.249.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this would work on plain Groovy, using the following syntax `env[key]` is not working here because pipeline is running inside a sandbox, where this type of access is not allowed.

You have two options there:

1 - Using Groovy gstrings and change `env[key]`to `env."${key}"` completely avoiding the sandbox error.

2 - If you still prefer this way of access, whitelisting the method on Jenkins management section called 'In-process Script Approval'. After doing that and running pipeline again, you should not see the stacktrace anymore.